# INTEL MKL ERROR when attempting to use Packages

Tags: python, pip, package

I recently installed Python on my work computer and I am having SO MANY issues with the packages, I can't use any of them.

Running simple matplotlib, numpy, or pandas code gives me the below error.

> INTEL MKL ERROR: The specified module could not be found. mkl_intel_thread.2.dll.
> Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.2.dll.

Here are the versions of the installed packages.

Numpy: 1.23.2 , Pandas: 1.4.4 , Matplotlib: 3.5.3 , Python: 3.10.6

When I attempt to update any of the with "pip install numpy --upgrade" it tells me that the requirement is already satisfied. Then, when I try to install with "pip install numpy --upgrade --ignore-installed" it tells me that it could not find a version that satisfies the requirement for numpy and no matching distribution for numpy.

Anything helps

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Numpy and other scientific libraries internally rely on certain numeric libraries (BLAS, LAPACK) for which there's a highly optimized version from Intel, which your python packages apparently cannot find (that's where that error around the `dll` comes from. These dlls aren't part of the python packages themselves.

You could look into a) installing the Intel MKL from scratch and see if that works or b) check if they're there and if you're missing a setting around a library path, some environment variable maybe.

If I may ask, *how* are you installing Python? On Windows in particular (I assume you're on windows because of the dll error message...) I'd recommend using Anaconda to install python. With such a package manager you might be able to avoid such dependency / path issues.